# I trying to install axios to my react project but there is an error

Tags: reactjs

this is the error I got when I tried to install axios in my react Project

```
PS C:\Users\mohamud\Desktop\reactapp> npm install axios

added 3 packages, and audited 1469 packages in 2m

225 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Comment: this is not an error

Comment: delano van londen if it is not error what is it? I tried everything I could and it is not running yet so can you please help?

Comment: what you pasted here is not an error, it still should run fine. the high severity vulnerabilities is something you will get with most packages